# base for setQueueXmlPath

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I can't figure out how to point unit tests at the queue config file.

Unit Test snippet

```
// TaskQueue setup
LocalTaskQueueTestConfig tqConfig = new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig();
tqConfig.setQueueXmlPath("/war/WEB_INF/queue.xml");
```

Stack Trace

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   specified queue is unknown : zip-fetch
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:56)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.translateError(QueueApiHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueApiHelper.makeSyncCall(QueueApiHelper.java:32)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:267)
>     at ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LocalTaskQueueTestConfig tqConfig = new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig();
tqConfig.setQueueXmlPath("war/WEB-INF/queue.xml");
```

It is relative to the root of the project or [an absolute path](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalTaskQueueTestConfig#setQueueXmlPath%28java.lang.String%29).
I had an underscore instead of a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Per the javadoc, setQueueXmlPath must be the full path

public LocalTaskQueueTestConfig setQueueXmlPath(java.lang.String queueXmlPath)
Overrides the location of queue.xml. Must be a full path, e.g. /usr/local/dev/myapp/test/queue.xml

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalTaskQueueTestConfig#setQueueXmlPath(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work with my maven project (using GAE 1.7.3), I had to specify the full path of the test location:

```
LocalTaskQueueTestConfig tqConfig = new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig();
tqConfig.setQueueXmlPath("src/test/resources/queue.xml");
```

Comment: This appears to be the relative path from the root of your project. You just happen to have a different project structure then I did. Maybe its a maven thing, but it looks odd to have a war folder inside a src folder.

Comment: and it looks like you have two queue.xml files: one in a test folder and one that is not. is that correct? is that on purpose?

Comment: I updated my answer a bit - the "war" folder was unnecessary.  Also, I think my answer is identical to yours, except I'm using maven.  Because of my maven project structure, it wasn't immediately clear to me that I needed to specify the whole maven folder structure -- I initially was trying "/queue.xml" and "queue.xml" thinking that would be the root of the class-path and the file would be found there.